# Do only reflexive spaces have a predual for the dual James map?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators, reflexive-space

Suppose $V$ is a Banach space and let $j_0\in V\to V^{**}$, $j_1\in V^*\to V^{***}$ be the canonical isometries into the double-dual.  If $V$ is reflexive, then $j_0$ is a surjection; moreover one can compute $j_1=(j_0^{-1})^*$ by unraveling the definitions.

But what if $V$ is not reflexive?  **When does there exist a map $T\in V^{**}\to V$ such that $j_1=T^*$?**  Since $j_1$ is always injective, $T$ [must](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510767/t-is-surjective-if-and-only-if-the-adjoint-t-is-an-isomorphism-onto-its-i) be a surjection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Such a $T$ exists iff $\text{im}(j_0)$ is complemented in $V^{**}$.**

If the image of $j_0$ is complemented (like, for example, James' space), then $T$ can be the projection from $V^{**}$ onto $\text{im}{(j_0)}$.

Conversely, if $T$ exists, then $j_0T$ must project $V^{**}\to\text{im}{(j_0)}$.  But then $V^{**}=\ker{(T)}\oplus\text{im}{(j_0)}$.

Comment: What are you asking the question if you have an answer?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: To record it for posterity, so that I can Google search it, and so that others can Google search it.